8x8 Thermo Sudoku with no clues
Attribution: Me
Rules of Thermo Sudoku:

Numbers placed in cells overlaid by a thermometer must increase in value from the circle bulb to the other end.

Objective:

Fill in the 8x8 Sudoku such that each row, column, and 2x4 subgrid that compose the grid contains the digits 1-8

Puzzle:

Time estimate: 30min-45min
Note: I have been able to verify with https://www.f-puzzles.com/ that this is indeed solvable, and have also solved this by hand to get an estimate of how much time it should take to solve.

I believe this is the filled grid (please ignore my poor editing skill):

 

For an explanation, it will be easier to keep track of if we notate squares in some way; since I am a bit lazy and it’s an 8x8 board, let’s steal chess’s labeling system:


 Let’s start with a4. It is the only square on its column that does not have a number greater than it, so it is an 8. Similarly, a3 is the only square on its column that does not have two numbers greater than it, so it is a 7. Continuing on, b8 is the only square in its box that does not have a number greater than it, so, it is an 8. Since there is now an 8 on the eighth row, row 7’s 8 must be on the e-h column; e7, f7, and g7 all have a number bigger than them, so 8 must be on h7. From here, h8 is the only space in its box without a number bigger than it; since 8 is accounted for, it is a 7. g7 is now the only space in its box where the 6 can go, as all of the other spaces in the box save e7 are directly on the same thermometer as it, and e7 has three numbers that are greater than it. So g7 must be 6. The 6 in box a must be on row 8; it cannot be on a8 because it has four numbers bigger than it and it cannot go on d8 because it has one number bigger than it that hasn’t been filled in already and 7 is accounted for on row 8. Therefore, it goes on c8. Let’s take a step back and look at what we’ve filled in so far:


 


 Let’s look at eights in the e-h 3-4 box. Row 4 and column h are covered. f3 and g3 have a number bigger than them, so it goes on e3. Moving to the a-d 1-2 box, the a and b columns are covered, and c1 is the only remaining spot without a number bigger than it, so the 8 goes there. Now, there needs to be a 7 on row 7, and the only spot there without two numbers greater than it is d7. This obviously results in the 8 going on d6.


 


 Looking at the a-d 5-6 box, the 7 must be placed on column c, since d already has a 7 and all other spaces have a number bigger than them (and 8 is accounted for). Therefore, it must go in column b on box a-d 1-2 (since a, c, and d are now all covered.) b2 must be greater than b1 and 8 is accounted for, so 7 goes on b2. Let’s take a break from high numbers and go low. a5 is the only space on column a without a number less than it, so it is the only spot for 1. Now that row 5 is covered, f6 is the only viable spot in its box for 1. Subsequently, 2 must go on g6, since it’s the only spot in its row without 2 numbers less than it. Since the sixth column is covered, b5 is the only possible spot in its box for 2. c5 must be 3, since the only other viable spot in its box, a6, would require a 2 on a7 and a 1 on a8, and there is already a 1 on column a. Now that c5 is covered, c6 is the only spot left for 7 in that box.


 


 Now, let’s look at a8. It has to be 2 or 3, since 4 would result in too few numbers between 4 and the 7 on c6. Let’s assume it was 3. Then a7 would be 4, a6 would be 5, and b6 would be 6. That would make d5 4, which is impossible since it has four numbers less than it. Therefore, a8 must be 2. We can employ similar logic for a7; it cannot be 4 for the exact same reason, so it must be 3. Same thing for a6 and 5- it must be 4. (We don’t know about b6 yet; it still can be 6 because d5 could still be 5.) 5 and 6 are the only remaining numbers on column a, and they can easily be filled in- 5 on a1 and 6 on a2. Let’s back up again:


 


 Now, we know 1 must go in row 8 in box e-h 7-8, because both remaining spots on row 7 have a number smaller than them. So 1 cannot go on d8, so it must go on b7. Looking now at row 6, there are only 3, 5, and 6 remaining to place. e6 cannot be 5 or 6, because that would force d5 to be 7 or 8, which is impossible because there is already a 7 and 8 in its box. This forces e6 to be 3, which forces e7 and e8 to be 2 and 1 respectively. Now that column e is covered, h4 is the only option in its box for 1. From here, we can finish up the ones: c2 (since column b is covered), then g1 and d3. Since column b is covered, c3 is the only possible place for a 2 in box a-d 3-4. Similarly, d2 must also be a 2.


 


 The 3 in box a-d 3-4 must go in column b, since d4 has two smaller numbers and 1 and 2 are accounted for, so it can’t go on b1. Therefore, the 3 in box a-d 1-2 must go on d1. 4 is the only remaining option in its box for b1. We can finish off the 2s with f4 and then h1. Since 1 and 2 are covered in box e-h 3-4, 3 cannot go on g4 since there would be no option for f3 otherwise. Therefore, the 3 on box a-d 3-4 must be on row 4; 1 and 2 are also covered there so it goes on b4. Now, the only place for 4 in that box is c4 (since b3 is covered.) We can also fill in c7 (5) and then f7 and d8 (4), since they are the only spots remaining in their column and row.


 


 5 must go on g8 because it is greater than 4; that leaves 3 to go on f8. With the 3 on f8, the only remaining possible spot for 3 in box e-h 3-4 is g3, and the final 3 goes on h2. The only spot for 4 in box e-h 3-4 is h3. The only possible number that can go in g4 now is 7.


 


 From here, the puzzle satisfyingly falls apart. The only possible spot for 7 in the e-h 1-2 box is e1. f1 must then be a 6, so f2 must be an 8, and e4 must be a 6, so d4 and f3 must both be 5. From there, b3 and d5 must be 6, b6 must be a 5, and h6 must be 6, and h5 must be a 5. e5 can’t be an 8, so g5 must be. From there, e5 and g2 must be 4, and e2 must be 5.


 

And just like that, we’re done- no guesswork necessary.

That would be correct, yes.

@CrSb0001 Great! I'm working on a step-by-step solution that will be edited in shortly; I started with a bit of guess and check but I think it is solvable systematically as well.

Nice! It is solvable systematically - although it is just really advanced applications of naked/hidden singles. In fact, really the estimated solve time (to be more accurate) should be around 1h-1h15min to be more accurate (I had taken ~2h30min to solve it myself)

Write up looks good!

@CrSb0001 thank you!
